# jquery .load target showing up on a new page

Tags: jquery

When I use the `.load()` function in jQuery, my target is on the same page, but for some reason it keeps giving me a new page.

Here is the code:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $("#searchResults").load('@(Url.Action("GetSearchResults", "MyController"))');
});
```

I have a div on the same page called `#searchResults`

The `GetSearchResults` Action in my controller actually returns a partial view that contains a Telerik data grid.

My expectation is that the partial view will get loaded into the `#searchResults` div using Ajax without refreshing the page.  But, a new page shows up instead with the partial view instead of it updating the `#searchResults` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return false at the end of your submit event to prevent the default browser handling of the submit.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
      $("#searchResults").load('@(Url.Action("GetSearchResults", "MyController"))');
      return false;
});
```